# Raiha chases the quints and Fuutarou with some thing

Tags: the-quintessential-quintuplets

In the s1 intro, Raiha chases the quints and Fuutarou with some thing. What is this? It doesn't seem to show up in the whole of s1 and s2.

(Ideally, I'd combine all 3 images below in 1 image, but it's too large to upload.)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on these tweets, it appears to be some kind of cat-bear called クマティー(KUMATTY)

https://twitter.com/marine__moon/status/1088054345365520389

https://twitter.com/quintupletbride/status/1088061007006580736

> [image]

> [image]

Nino actually owns some Kumatty merchandise.

In manga:

> [image]

> [image]

> [image]

In anime:

> [image]

> [image]